# variable returns undefined inside of map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function and inside the function I have the following code:

```
storeobj = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('domehaProducts'));
    console.log("Store: " + JSON.stringify(storeobj))


// Merge products and cart data
var cart = order.items.map(item => {
    storeobj = this.storeobj.products.find(prod => prod.id == item.id);
    return Object.assign(item, { images: storeobj.image, name: storeobj.name, price: storeobj.display_price, intPrice: storeobj.price});
});
```

In line 7 `this.storeobj` returns undefined but `console.log` logs it successfully on line 2.

I have tried it with and without `this` can't can't seem to get it to recognize the variable.

EDIT: I have `store = localStorage` at the top.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`storeobj` variable overrides during first map iteration and you don't need to use `this`.

```
storeItem = JSON.parse(storage.getItem('domehaProducts'));

let cart = order.items.map(item => {
    const storeobj = storeItem.products.find(prod => prod.id == item.id);
    return Object.assign(item, { images: storeobj.image, name: storeobj.name, price: storeobj.display_price, intPrice: storeobj.price});
});
```